Difficulty Adding "Outfit" Google Font in Flutter
I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter project where I'm unable to add the "Outfit" Google Font. Previously, I successfully added it in earlier code, but now I'm facing difficulties including it in my current project.
I've followed the standard procedure of adding Google Fonts in Flutter by specifying the font family in my pubspec.yaml file and then using it in my code with TextStyle. However, despite having used "Outfit" before, it's not working now.
Despite following steps showned by google, the "Outfit" font doesn't appear to be applied. I've ensured that the font file is correctly placed in the assets folder and referenced in the pubspec.yaml file.
Can anyone please guide me on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Added the font family to pubspec.yaml

 fonts:
  - family: Outfit
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/Outfit-Regular.ttf

Expected Outcome
I expected the "Outfit" font to be applied to the text as it was in previous iterations of my project. However, despite these steps, the "Outfit" font doesn't appear to be applied. I've ensured that the font file is correctly placed in the assets folder and referenced in the pubspec.yaml file.

You need to use the font family in the app itself. Pass the font family in the theme data
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Outfit'),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

this will apply the font family globally.
If you want to apply it to specific text only, you can add it to text style as :
        Text(
            'THIS IS TEXT',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Outfit',
            ),
          ),

